# seaborn.boxplot and wide-format dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

[image: dataframe]

I tried these two instructions one after another:

```
sns.boxplot([dataFrame.mean_qscore_template,dataFrame.mean_qscore_complement,dataFrame.mean_qscore_2d])

sns.boxplot(x = "mean_qscore_template", y= "mean_qscore_complement", hue = "mean_qscore_2d" data = tips)
```

I want to get `mean_qscore_template`,  `mean_qscore_complement` and `mean_qscore_2d` on the x-axis with the measure on y-axis but it doesn't work.

[image]

In the documentation they give an example with tips but my `dataFrame` is not organized f the same way.

Comment: Please, provide sample code that not working for you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sns.boxplot(data = dataFrame)` will make boxplots for each numeric column of your dataframe.